# Epson TM-T20II Printer not able to print via javascript sdk

Tags: javascript, thermal-printer, epson, printing-web-page

I downloaded the JavaScript SDK for Epson printer that supports TM-t20ii.
i was able to print test page using the following url:

```
http://192.168.2.175:9100/
```

Printer and pc connected via Ethernet and i am able to ping the printer url

Output:

```
OPTIONS /cgi-bin/epos/service.cgi?devid=99&timeout=10000 HTTP/1.1
Host: 192.168.2.175:9100
Connection: keep-alive Access-Control-Request-Method: POST
Origin: null
User-Agent: Mizilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/52.0.2743.116 Safari/537.36
Access-Control-Request-Headers: content-type, if-modified-since, soapaction
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate,sdch
Accept=Language: en-US, en;q=0.8
```

but in order to Print the following request should be Used:

```
http://192.168.1.175/cgi-bin/epos/service.cgi?devid=999&timeout=10000
```

(if i use the same request with 9100 port i get the same result printing output for http://192.168.2.175:9100/

```
405 (Method Not Allowed)

Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://192.168.2.172' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 405
```

i have read that i have to  enable the ePOS-Print setting from within the EpsonNet Config on the printer but the config does not have such option.

i cant determine how to check if this setting is enabled or not OR what port should be used or if any other configuration is required,i checked the printer manual and printer sdk with no luck.

Comment: Hi. Did you have any luck with this afterwards. I've been stuck on a similar issue where the EpsonNetConfig(Web for the one I'm using TM-U220) does not have this option.

Comment: hello we used this plugin:
https://github.com/aelx311/cordova-plugin-epos2 
since are app was a hybrid mobile app built with phonegap and cordova.js

Comment: thanks but we found out that there was a lack of clear documentation nor support officially. Also we were focused on a desktop based web app so we found a more suitable library [Node ESCPOS] (https://github.com/song940/node-escpos) for our needs :)

Comment: @gabyawad,
Were you able to make print from a HTTPS web app? Did you face cross content issues? If, yes then how were you able to resolve?

Comment: @NirajPatel we needed the functionality for a mobile app ,we ended up using this library:
https://github.com/cspsolutions/epson_printer

but also it does not have support for everything.

Answer (score 0):

In latest version **2.12.0** they have added support for TM-T20III, TM-T82III printer model.

Download latest SDK from below link and try

https://download.epson-biz.com/modules/pos/index.php?page=single_soft&cid=6167&scat=57&pcat=52

Comment: Hi. I've got the TM-T20III but my model is USB (doesn't have ethernet). Is it possible to still use their SDK? Their `connect` method accepts an IP address but my printer being USB won't have any, right?